# Multiple statements found error in python for a user input function

Tags: python

I'm using the book "Python In Easy Steps" by Mike Mcrath,and I'm having a issue with the user input project. I keep getting the error "multiple statements found while compiling a single statement".

```
user = input('Hello, my name is Hal. What is your name?:')

print( ' It is very nice to meet you',user)
```

I'm using the 3.4.3 version of the IDLE shell to test my code.

Comment: How are you running the code? Is it a separate script?

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute them one by one :

```
user = input('Hello, my name is Hal. What is your name?:')
```

it will ask for input and then:

```
print( ' It is very nice to meet you',user)
```

**or** create a Python script (.py) and then from terminal exexute:

```
python filename.py
```

Comment: IDLE can only do a single statement at once, i.e. in your case: A single line. So you have to paste in all lines individually and execute them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print ('It is very nice to meet you %s' % user)
```

Answer (score 0):

`print 'It is very nice to meet you %s' % user`

Comment: I did not know IDLE could only do one statement at a time. I ran it from the Terminal a few other times and got the same error, but this time it worked. I guess I needed to mess around with the indentations in Notepad. Thanks for the help guys.